# Total sum of a list of numbers with list iteration

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

```
num = {"functions": 10, "syntax": 13, "flow": 15, "loops": 22, "lists": 19}
total = 0
```

This doesn't work:

```
total += num for num in num.values():
```

This does:

```
for num in num_exercises.values():

    total_exercises += num
```

There is not much difference in terms of effort or character length but for the general understanding of syntax it would be nice to get it explained.

I couldn't answer this question myself by googling or try and error.

Comment: `num for num in num.values()` is a generator expression, and you can't add a generator expression to an integer. You could do `total += sum(...)`.

Comment: You can't just flip things around and expect it to work. That is the reason.

Comment: If you want to do it in one line: `total = sum(num.values())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
total += sum(num.values())
```

The former one doesn't work because of many reasons, one of the most prominent is because you're putting the list comprehension loop syntax(idk if im pronouncing it correctly but you can see it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)) outside of parantheses.

See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

Your first inline piece of code is almost a generator expresion, but has a `:` at the end which would be a `SyntaxError`.

You should use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) here:

```py
total = sum(num.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you did a syntax error that's why your code doesn't work. I did according to your code

```
num = {"functions": 10, "syntax": 13, "flow": 15, "loops": 22, "lists": 19}
total = 0
for val in num.values():
    total += val
print(total)
```

**Output is** `79`

You can get sum of values in many more ways. If you want to get the result using the sum function then follow the first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65233717/5929910) Then you can also store sum value to total variable then follow 2nd [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65233775/5929910)